# FireDAC load data from Access file into DBGrid without using drag and drop control

Tags: delphi, firedac

I want to make a DLL to connect to access using fireDAC without using drag and drop control on the form, I have searched a lot of documents and videos, they only do drag and drop, can anyone explain to me how fireDAC works. through the code below, but it fails

```
procedure TForm1.btnLoadAccessClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  cnn : TFDConnection;
  qry : TFDQuery;
  src : TDataSource;
  driver : TFDPhysMSAccessDriverLink;
begin
  cnn:=TFDConnection.Create(nil);
  driver.Create(nil);
  driver.ODBCDriver:='Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)';
  driver.DriverID:='ODBC';
  try
    cnn.Params.DriverID:='ODBC';
    cnn.Params.Database:='data.mdb';
    cnn.Connected:=True;
    qry:=TFDQuery.Create(nil);
    try
      src.Create(nil);
      qry.Connection:=cnn;
      qry.SQL.Text:='select * From Staff';
      qry.Open;
      qry.active:=true;
      src.DataSet:=qry;
      DBGrid1.DataSource:=src;
    finally
      qry.Free
    end;
  finally
  cnn.Free;
  src.Free;
  driver.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I just need to read the data from the access file, can you help me?

Comment: There are some serious mistakes in you Code.
1.) Driver.Create(nil) will raise a access violation. You cant create a Class from itself
2.) The correct Driver ID for Access is MSAcc
3.) The Database Name has to contain the Full Path to your Database
But, why do you make your life so complicated? Create a Datamodule, add FDConnection and AccessDriverlink on it, set ConnectionDefName. Then on your targetsystem open FDExplorer (in Delphi bin folder), configure your Connection, save it as FDConnectionDefs.ini, put that file beside your dll and your done.

Comment: How is it that you know how to create an object instance correctly in one line of code (`cnn:=TFDConnection.Create(nil)`) but suddenly don't know how to do it in the **very next line of code** when you write `driver.Create(nil)`? The same applies everywhere else in your code. Did you even read your own code? It's important when learning to program that you understand the code you're writing, rather than just throwing together random things from your keyboard.